# How to dynamically select values in Multiselect combo box - LovCombo ExtJS 3.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I am using lovcombo in ExtJS 3.2. I fetch the data for initial loading of combo box and I am getting it correctly. But now I have a requirement in which, lets say initially I got 10 entries (options) in combo box, I need to select now 5 options dynamically. Actually I am using it to show dependent entity mapping. Means one entity is dependent on many other entities, so showing them in multiselect combo box. When I get root entity, I need to fetch dependent entities for my root entity, and accordingly I will select those entries dynamically in combo box. This is my code -

```
{
    xtype: 'lovcombo',
    fieldLabel: 'data Requirement ',
    store: dep_req_store,
    displayField: 'text',
    valueField: 'value',
    mode: 'local',
    emptyText: 'Select Requirement...',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    name: 'data_id',
    id: 'data_id' + idSuf,
    hiddenName: 'reqIdHid3',
    width: 200,
    forceSelection: true,
    editable: true,
    hideOnSelect: false,
    beforeBlur: Ext.emptyFn,
}
```

I will iterate thru each element of this combo after its loaded and will select necessary options:

```
Ext.getCmp('data_id' + idSuf).getStore().data.items.each(function(record) {
    record.dirty = true; //I tried this but no success.
});
```

Also, I didn't find any attribute which can help me to select the option like:

```
record.selected = true
```

So, please help me in this. Is it possible to achieve this using lovcombo?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in record's field definition you can create a new field called `checked`, this field is by default used by lovcombo to store checked state of the record

```
fields: [
    ...
    {name: 'checked',  type: 'boolean'},
    ....
]
```

and when you want to check any record after loading it just do

```
record.set('checked', true);
```

[Reference:](http://lovcombo.extjs.eu/source.php?file=js/Ext.ux.form.LovCombo.js)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.! Actually I too find the way after wards like this - `record.set(this.checkField, true);` where `checkField` is its default property. Thanks again.!